# Delphi Database Connection to C:\ProgramFiles

Tags: delphi, inno-setup

I'm using the software Inno Setup in order to create an installer for my program, this installs the program to the C:\ProgramFiles(x86) folder, so Im linking my database connection to this new folder, however it won't let me link it as it says I don't have permission.

I am unsure of how to combat this error, as the database is the key part of my program and without it my program wont work.

Comment: Can you be more precise. What does "it won't let me link it" and "it says I don't have permission" actually mean? Be precise about the source and content of the error messages. Now, going beyond that, are you aware that standard user cannot write to program files directories? It does sound as though you are trying to store modifiable data to a program files directory. You must not do that. Program files directory contains static content.

Comment: I have a database which the program reads from and writes to, the error is like so, when i try putting the database source using an ADOConnection: OLDFILEPATH is not a valid file path. Make sure that the file path is spelt correctly and that you are connected to the server it resides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting a database under `C:\Program Files` or `C:\Program Files (x86)` is not a good idea.  Non-admin users don't have write access to those folder, and you should never give write access to it.

To be Windows conformant, you have two possibilities:

1. When your program starts the first time, copy a template database to the user's profile under `%AppData%\companyname\prgname` and use that from now on.
2. if you need different users to work on the same database, put the database under `%ProgramData%\companyname\prgname` instead, and don't forget to give user's write access to that folder.

Comment: Thank you, I feel a bit stupid now, just made a folder in the C drive and Pont the database there and this does the trick :)

Comment: @AdamHindle Directly under the `C:\\ ` root is also a bad idea. While it may allow you with no problem, this is the '90s way of doing things. The only reason applications typically do this these days is if these applications were designed a long time ago. Otherwise, you should follow Bernd's advice (which is Microsoft's advise too).

Comment: @AdamHindle can't recommend that. Try to follow the windows standards, please. Your new folder is accessible for everyone. there are no right restrictions. think about trojans and randsomware. If you not follow the standards you open your doors for losing data or get into trouble in future versions of windows.

Comment: @Adam Writing an installer requires a somewhat deeper understanding of the platform standards and conventions. It will pay for you to spend a little time learning about these matters.

Comment: Ok thank you guys, I have changed it now and it's all up and running. Appreciate the advice